# Checking null for multiple strings in Java

Tags: java, string, null

How can one check for whether one of the strings is not null, only if the rest contain something?

Here is an example of how it works, but I feel like there should be a better way to do it.

```
if ((string1 != null && !string1.equals("")) && 
    (string2 == null || string2.equals("") || string3 == null || string3.equals(""))) {
        // BAD
} else if ((string2 != null && !string2.equals("")) &&
    (string1 == null || string1.equals("") || string3 == null || string3.equals(""))) {
        // BAD
} else if ((string3 != null && !string3.equals("")) &&
    (string1 == null || string1.equals("") || string2 == null || string2.equals(""))) {
        // BAD
}
```

Is there a way to condense this logic into a better approach?

**EDIT**

If all strings are null, that's fine.

If all string aren't null, also fine.

If at least one is not null and at least one is null, not fine.

**SAMPLE**

```
public static void main(String []args){
     
    String string1 = "1";
    String string2 = "2";
    String string3 = "3";

    String stringA = "";
    String stringB = "";
    String stringC = "";

    String stringQ = "1";
    String stringW = "2";
    String stringY = "";

    // THIS IS FINE         
    System.out.println(isGood(string1, string2, string3));

    // THIS IS FINE         
    System.out.println(isGood(stringA, stringB, stringC));

    // THIS IS NOT FINE         
    System.out.println(isGood(stringQ, stringW, stringY));

}
 
public static boolean isGood (String ... strings) {

    long nullCount = Arrays.stream(strings)
        .filter(s -> s == null || s.isEmpty())
        .count();

    return strings.length == nullCount || nullCount == 0;
}
```

Comment: `String.isEmpty()` might help more than using `isEquals("")`.  And using an array might help as well, you could do this in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understood of your requirements in the comments this should work.

Count the number of null (or non null, either way works). Then compare that with the amount of strings passed into the method. If the count is neither the length of the list or 0 then it means there is a mix of not null or empty string vs null or empty strings (indicating it's bad).

```
public static boolean badStrings (String ... strings) {

    var nullCount = Arrays.stream(strings)
            .filter(s -> s == null || s.isEmpty())
            .count();

    return nullCount < strings.length && nullCount > 0;
}
```

Note that `count` returns `long` and `length` method of array will return an `int`.

Comment: What @markspace did was the same logic as a `for` loop and just reading his answer now the intended logic is the same.

Comment: What exactly is that scenario. I just caught that string3 is null/empty?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to benefit from a varargs in Java

```
if( badStrings( string1, string2, string3 ) ) {
   // bad
}

public boolean badStrings( String ... strings ) {
  for( int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++ ) {
     if( strings[i] != null && !strings[i].isEmpty() ) {
        return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
}
```

> It is not fine only when at least one is not null and at least one is null.

OK let's try this.

```
public boolean badStrings( String ... strings ) {
  int count = 0;
  for( int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++ ) {
     if( strings[i] != null && !strings[i].isEmpty() ) {
        count++;
     }
   }
   return !(count == 0 || count == strings.length-1)
}
```

Code is untested.

Comment: I ran this one and it looks like it still goes to `//bad` even if all strings are null/empty. If all null, that's fine. If all aren't null, also fine. It is not fine only when at least one is not null and at least one is null.

Comment: Thanks for giving it another go. When I run this with `string3` empty/null, it still doesn't work as expected. it does catch the ones where all do not exist though so that's good.

Comment: upvoted for mentioning using varargs (or you could do a list) instead of separate variables. Also the post needs to be updated to clarify the ask as it was mentioned in the comment above. Can you also put sample input output especially for the cases that are unique for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would like prefer this method, if this is an trust alternative:

```
@SafeVarargs
    final <T> boolean areAllNull(final T... objects) {
        return Arrays.stream(objects).noneMatch(Objects::nonNull);
//        return Arrays.stream(objects).allMatch(Objects::isNull);
    }
```